# Using more than one filter - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

everyone!

I'm trying to create a measure in Power BI using DAX, where i'm filtering 2 different date columns  (Data de Admissao and Data de Rescisao). "Data de admissão" tells when an employee was hired and "Data de rescisao" tells you when an employee left the company. I'm using a date table "DTempo". With the code below, I succeeded in filtering my active employees at a certain point in time.
Now, I need to add a filter by company structure, but these structures are text and I can't do the same thing that I did with DTempo.

Example: In 01/01/2020 I had 3000 employee in my company, while in my "sales" structure I had 1000 employees, but my measure "Ativos movel" does not respect the structure filter.

```
Ativos_móvel = CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Base FOPAG'),
        'Base FOPAG'[Data Admissão] <= MIN('DTempo'[Date]) &&
        OR('Base FOPAG'[Data de Rescisão] >= MIN(DTempo[Date]),
        ISBLANK('Base FOPAG'[Data de Rescisão])) &&
        'Base FOPAG'[Cargo] <> "CONSELHEIRO AUTONOMO" &&
        'Base FOPAG'[CARGO LÍDER] <> "AUTONOMO"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Is 'Base FOPAG' the company structure column that you are referring to? This should be clearly stated.

Comment: No. Sorry. The scructure column i'm referring to is 'Base FOPAG'[Estrutura]. Base FOPAG is my fact data base.
Completing the info:
Inside the column "Estrutura" I have "Lojas", "Escritorio" and "Logistica". I want to filter only "Lojas" and return the exact employee quantity I have in my "lojas" structure at a certain point in time.

Comment: When I use: 
'Base FOPAG'[Estrutura] = "Lojas" inside FILTER(), it works. But I need to replace "Lojas" with a filter I can switch between all the possibilities from column "Estrutura"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can add a additional filter parameters within the Calculate()  function

```
    Ativos_móvel =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Base FOPAG' ),
            'Base FOPAG'[Data Admissão] <= MIN ( 'DTempo'[Date] )
                && OR (
                    'Base FOPAG'[Data de Rescisão] >= MIN ( DTempo[Date] ),
                    ISBLANK ( 'Base FOPAG'[Data de Rescisão] )
                )
        )
    ),
    'Base FOPAG'[Cargo] <> "CONSELHEIRO AUTONOMO"
        && 'Base FOPAG'[CARGO LÍDER] <> "AUTONOMO"
)
```